# grep and ls: 'l' flag not supported for ls when used with xargs?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, ls, xargs

Why does **ls** not work when the -l flag is passed in combination with xargs and grep?

```
$ ls -rt | xargs grep xyz
```

works, but:

```
$ ls -lrt | xargs grep xyz
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: -l gives a timestamp for the returned files - see examples below

Answer (score 3):

Because the output for `ls -l` is similar to this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1491872 2012-11-22 03:07 Xvfb_screen0
```

Piping this to xargs (`ls -l | xargs grep xyz`) is making your grep command to be

```
grep xyz -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1491872 2012-11-22 03:07 Xvfb_screen0
```

And it does not have any sense.

**edit**

to answer @vladr comment here because it has better formatting than the comments box. Each whitespace separated text from the input of xargs is passed as a new param to the executed command, as you can see:

```
$ ls -l 
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 carlos carlos 18 2012-11-22 15:17 foo

$ cat foo
#!/bin/sh
echo $#

$ ls -l | xargs ./foo
10
```

It's possible to behave the way you say by setting the delimiter in `xargs` to `\n`:

```
$ ls -l | xargs -d '\n' ./foo
2
```

Comment: You get so used to using -lrt over the years, you stop realizing the "long" part is not normal :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, **specifically**, use `ls -lrt | xargs grep xyz --` (notice the `--`, which signifies that any dashes `-` that appear afterwards are to be taken literally, not as option flags -- see [@CarlosCampderrós's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514508/66516) for what your command expands to), but **I strongly doubt that you have the correct setup** to begin with, as it is **unlikely to achieve anything useful, as used**.

**More likely** you are trying to grep for `xyz` in all files in reverse chronological order.  If so then use `ls -1rt | xargs grep xyz --` (notice dash-one `-1`, *not* dash-ell `-l`.)  The `--` is truly optional in this case (unless you expect one or more files' name(s) to begin with dash `-`.)